# Reasons for using Variable Argument Lists versus vector (c++)

Tags: c++, vector, stl, variadic-functions

I am trying to understand Variable Argument Lists (varargs). I have previously used pointers and/or *std::vector* for parameters which can change in the amount of objects that need to be passed.

I would expect that Varargs ([1](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson17.html),[2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic)) and Vectors ([3](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/vector.html),[4](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) as part of function parameters both have their own special uses in C++ and are better at different things. However, I am having a difficult time distinguishing when *std::vector* is not the right choice. Could this please be explained?

Is this the type of scenario where varargs might be preferred?

```
union S //Using union from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union
{
    std::int32_t n;     // occupies 4 bytes
    std::uint16_t s[2]; // occupies 4 bytes
    std::uint8_t c;     // occupies 1 byte
};                      // the whole union occupies 4 bytes


int myFunction(std::vector<S> v)
```

Comment: well you can - his code shows it , but the functionality is obscured

Answer (score 2):

[`std::printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) is a great example!

The reason why varargs are used for `std::printf` is **usability**, especially for the programmer.

Why do *you* have to create a vector to call `std::printf`. It's just a pain.. Also, you would have to pass the parameters in groups of their respective types, because `std::vector` can't store different types:

```
//This would be horrible!
std::vector<std::string> text{ "Your age is" };
std::vector<std::string> text2{ "!" };
std::vector<int> age{ 26 };

//....
std::bad_print(text);
std::bad_print(age);
std::bad_print(text2);
```

Here it is obvious that varargs (or variadic templates, same thing) would be much better, and increase productivity, speed and memory:

```
//Much better
std::printf("%s %i %s", "Your age is ", age, "!");

//Even better
std::good_print("Your age is ", age, "!"); //Uses varargs or variadic templates
```

So, it depends. If you know how many arguments you are going to pass to the function at compile time, then use varargs (or variadic templates), because there is no reason in creating a seperate `std::vector` to store those values.

If you don't know the values, such as when the user inputs them, then using a `std::vector` is appropriate.

Comment: Or `std::cout << "You age is " << age << "!";` *Look ma - no varargs!*

Comment: @Bo yeah, but this question is _about_ varargs :)

Answer (score 1):

varargs  is for when the caller has a fixed set of things in mind and the called function will take anything. like printf

```
printf(".....", foo, wiz, count);
```

I dont need this one invocation to take different numbers of parameters. Also varargs is much clearer if the args are of different types

Comment: ... and you can't pass your varargs to a function that takes ..., you'll need a separate function that takes va_list. This is not always possible if the code you call is in a different library and the library writer didn't provide two sets of functions: one with ..., one with const va_list&

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a virtual function, or you're pre-C++11, I'd suggest against varargs and for template parameter packs ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack ). They achieve the same goal, but parameter packs are type-safe and you don't need two sets of functions when a varargs calls another varargs. Also, variants instead of unions if you have boost.
The other thing, if you call a virtual function from your varargs function (and pass va_list), the implementation might parse a type from it that your compilation unit doesn't even know of. Thus you can't specify a finite union all the times.

Comment: Btw, does anyone have a good type-safe solution in place of va_list for virtual functions where set of possible argument types is not known beforehand?